My Raspberry Pi 3B+ has been running FR24 since 2018
My Raspberry Pi 3B+ has been running FR24 since 2018. This year 2024 we had an extended power outage and my battery backup went dead. Since this time i tried to get the HDMI output to work, I thought maybe it was the Cable, replaced the cable no signal detected, I bought a new screen still no HDMI detected, So I've been reading up about reinstalling SD software and including some code. But if I cant see a screen to write code then what? Now, I do have Windows systems but can I write code through windows?
I'm a novice to RP systems, but love how clean and good they are. Any help would be appreciated.

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question? I don't know what FR24 is but if you are running an 7 year old unsupported OS your only options are to restore from your backup OR start again with a current OS.

the title should describe the problem ... please update it

It's possible the SD card has died...they don't last forever unfortunately. The RPi can also give some indication of certain faults.  Try Googling 'RPi 3B+ power-on error codes' to see what some of the error indications are.
When you say "running FR24", what do you mean? If this is Flight Radar 24 are you just downloading and displaying from the website, or do you have an ADS-B receiver attached to your RPi that is feeding into FR24?
